# Find indexPath of cell by label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have table with cells; each cell contain label with phone number. When i tap on the label, `UIMenuController` appears.

Is there a main way to find indexPath of cell, which contain selected label? (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` should not be called)

I can imagine many dirty hacks, but i looking for a main/good solution.

**upd**

I have reference to selected label.

Comment: hi, why didSelectRowAtIndexPath should not be called ?

Comment: For fist, i wont select row when just touch label, for second, in this method i can just store indexPath, which came as a parameter. @James03

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

This is a better way.

```
- (IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender {
    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView]; 
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
}
```

Comment: Pretty easy! Tell me please, why .superview called twice?

Comment: contentView exists in iOS 7 tableViewCells

Comment: Do the edited answer in your IBAction method that contains the sender and done. Much cleaner.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but you beat me to it. (Voted)

Answer (score 1):

From your label, search for the cell object in the label's hierarchy:

```
-(UITableViewCell*) cellContainingView:(UIView*)view
{
    UIView* currentView = view;
    while (currentView)
    {
        if ([currentView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            return (UITableViewCell*)currentView;
        }
        currentView = currentView.superview;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Once you have the cell, call `[tableView indexPathForCell:cell]`
The use of this method instead of hard coding view.superview.superview makes your code stronger because it handle possible changes in cell's view hierarchy through system's versions.

Comment: Using the UITableView method `indexPathForRowAtPoint:`, as described in DCGoD's answer, is much cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score -1):

You could go:

```
NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
    {
        [cells addObject:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]];
    }
}

for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells){
   for (UILabel *label in cell.subviews){
        if (label == yourLabel)
           indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell: cell];
   }
}
```

Comment: I know this algorithm, but i should scan whole the table and thats scare me (because O(n)).

Comment: You could avoid the O(n) problem using the UITableView method 
indexPathsForVisibleRows, and then check that list, but using the UITableView method indexPathForRowAtPoint:, as described in DCGoD's answer, is much cleaner and simpler.